# unable to download playwright by the command npx playwright install

Tags: npm, playwright, npx, playwright-test

Operating System: Windows

Node.js version: v16.14.2

I cannot install playwright through the command 'npx playwright install'. When I typed 'npx playwright install', it started to download browsers, but when it reached 99% it stuck there (like in the picture below)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thp8g.png)

Comment: It can have multiple reasons, most likely you have either issues with your internet connection or some special anti virus software installed which blocks the browsers from being downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Windows, it might be that you didn't Run as Administrator and this script is unable to move the downloaded files somewhere that requires more privileges.